# Logo and sitewide images refuse to be responsive

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

I am creating a simple wordpress theme for [this website](http://cyprus-citizenship.com) and [style.css](http://cyprus-citizenship.com/wp-content/themes/ezy-theme/style.css?ver=4.3.1) applied on this site.

i want all images to be responsive. I tried this code.

```
img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

It is not working unfortunately. If you try to resize the browser, the logo and the image is not resizing according to browser width (unresponsive).

How do i fix this?

Sorry for being so naive, been working on this for 2 days, still cant seem to find a solution for this simple problem.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `max-width: 100%;` try the following:

```
img {
   max-width: 200px; /* Change this to what your logo is by its width */
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

You can also set the max-width to be more than what your logo actually is, but of course it is suggested to keep it at high quality and in control.

**EDIT:** For sitewide images this of course does not work, since they all don't have the same width.

Comment: Is there any other one liner?

Answer (score 0):

For image tag write this css

```
img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
width:100%;
}
```

And if you are using bootstrap in your theme then write this css

```
img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
width:100%;
display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Nope, used width:100%, it zooms the image appears so big.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the images in a div, with a media query for true mobile. Here I made a version that's three images across and turn into stacked images on mobile, resizing along the way: [Example is here](http://jsfiddle.net/ug9u898y/)

```
<div class="image-wrap">
    <img alt="" src="http://test.amtamassage.org/wp-content/uploads/5904-thumb-290x220-cropped.jpg">
</div>
    <div class="image-wrap">
    <img alt="" src="http://test.amtamassage.org/wp-content/uploads/5904-thumb-290x220-cropped.jpg">
</div>
        <div class="image-wrap">
    <img alt="" src="http://test.amtamassage.org/wp-content/uploads/5904-thumb-290x220-cropped.jpg">
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.image-wrap {
      max-width: 600px;
      width: 30%;
      margin: 2% 0 0 2%;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      display: inline;
      float: left; }
    img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto; }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .image-wrap {
        width: 96%;
        max-width: 400px;
        display: block;
        float: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 2%;}
    }
```